# Error in SQL query GROUP BY clause; sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-mode

Please help me with this SQL query; when I use a `GROUP BY` clause, I get this error from Mysql:

> This is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I want different values on column: B.shopname.

```
SELECT 
    A.id,
    COUNT(A.id),
    A.idShop,
    B.shopname
FROM 
    A 
INNER JOIN 
    B ON A.idShop = B.id
GROUP BY 
    B.shopname
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except_ those who are arguments to set function. I.e. try `GROUP BY A.id, A.idShop, B.shopname`.

Comment: you should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` columns are incompatible with the `SELECT` columns.  Why?  The query is trying to `SELECT` three unaggregated columns, `A.id`, `A.idShop`, and `B.shopname`.  However, the `GROUP BY` only includes one of those.

The general recommendation is to add all unaggregated columns into the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT A.id, COUNT(A.id), A.idShop, B.shopname
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B
     ON A.idShop = B.id
GROUP BY A.id, A.idShop, B.shopname;
```

But I don't think this will do what you want.  I am guessing that the `COUNT()` will always be `1`.  I suspect you want:

```
SELECT B.idShop, B.shopname, COUNT(*)
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B
     ON A.idShop = B.id
GROUP BY B.id, B.shopname;
```

Notes:

- `A.id` is no longer in the `SELECT`.  It is not appropriate because you want to *count* the values.
- I doubt that `A.id` is ever `NULL`, so counting the non-`NULL` values of the column just clutters the query.  `COUNT(*)` is clearer (although some folks prefer `COUNT(1)`).
- It is better to have `GROUP BY` keys all be from the same table because it gives the optimizer more options.